# Deal with the multiple-version tagging

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags

I've seen a lot of people tag their questions like this:

My Question

<-insert some crappy gimme teh codez question here->

Tags

[c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) [c#-2.0](/questions/tagged/c%23-2.0) [c#-3.0](/questions/tagged/c%23-3.0) [c#-4.0](/questions/tagged/c%23-4.0) [c#-5.0](/questions/tagged/c%23-5.0)

This would be fine if only a handful of newbies did this, but I notice quite a few people doing this (normally about 5 an hour, depends on the time). Is there any way we could stop this?

Comment: Yes, you can retag every wrong tagged question on sight.

Comment: Well, either you're wrong or people are doing an exceptionally good job of retagging these as soon as they appear. Because I don't see very many questions that have multiple inappropriate version tags.

Comment: People retag these but it gets annoying.

Comment: In fact, the bigger problem appears to be the use of a single version-specific tag when a general tag should have been used. I suppose this is less likely to be fixed as there are fewer people monitoring the version-specific tags. Not sure how we fix either of them, though. There's a human factor to the tag system. If people don't pick the right tags, their questions don't get answered.